# How to import Angular Seed project in IntelliJ

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea, angular-seed

I'm trying to import the Angular Seed project into IntelliJ, but when I do it creates a whole bunch of individual modules. I just want a view of the directory structure and to forget about this module junk. All they are are folders to me.

How can I set this up in IntelliJ? Is this something people do with Angular applications or do I need to change to something like WebStorm instead?

Comment: I cloned the seed project and imported it and it came out fine but the yeoman generated project, on the other hand, turned into mush in IJ.

Comment: Yeah it did turn the subsections into modules: angular, app, config, e2e, scripts, unit. I guess that's suboptimal.

Comment: Yep, it sucks - anyone have any idea how to make this not happen?

Comment: JetBrains is a total riddle to me: some stuff is outstanding, some is like swiss cheese. The Play and SBT support is still pretty sucky. Gradle too. Bringing projects in is in general not great. Might be a good idea to make project files and fork the seed and have an IJ version.

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to web projects in IDEA, you have to do the following to make it bahave more or less like WebStorm: (I too think IDEA is terrible at setting up a simple custom project)

Make the web project or other random file structure a Module inside a project.

--edit--
I just realized that creating a new project allows you to directly go for a Web Module. This way there is no need for a 6-step plan. :)
--edit 2--
You can specify the Module File Location here just as easy.

Here's how I do it:

1. Make a new empty project, like `~/MyDevStuff/OSProjects/`
2. Open project settings
3. Modules > + > New module > Web Module
4. Your sources should be placed in the project as a subdirectory `angular-seed/`
5. Name the module, probaly same as directory name.
6. (Optional) point Module File Location to the project dit to avoid having the `.iml` file with your angular-seed files.

Comment: What version are you talking about? On Idea 13.1.3 I don't have any module type "web module". I have Static web...

Comment: I am on 14 - there is only static web, and I can't get any script I src to be found, no idea what path to use as none work, need some kind of static-web-tutorial.

Comment: Intellij's static web angular template, or possibly all of them, are trash.

Answer (score 0):

In according to official [jetbrains documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/angular.html):

> To open the application sources that are already on your machine
>   Click Open on the Welcome screen or choose File | Open on the main
>   menu. In the dialog that opens, select the folder where your sources
>   are stored.